# Show two forms in one HTML horizantally

Tags: html, css

I want to change the login page of my site.

I need to add a registration form on the login page, so that page would have two forms: one for login and the other for registration.

I don't know how to set these forms horizontally. Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: keep them in `div`s and use `float:left`

Comment: @BhuvanRikka no need of div,just add float to form

Comment: @Ankit Gautam There are many ways to do it mate. And that is my way of doing it. Nothing is wrong in it

Answer (score 2):

This should give you an idea of what you need to do:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form form1">Form 1</div>
    <div class="form form2">Form 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.form {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

.form1 {
    background:#ccc;
}

.form2 {
    background:#999;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/scjBv/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left`:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```css
input { display: block; }
form { float: left; padding-left: 15px; }
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/27gyOpEw)**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to put these forms into divs?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">LEFT FORM</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT FORM</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left { 
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
.right {
    width:300px;
}
.clear {
    clear:left;
}
```